# I keep losing my saved game in Darksiders. How do I fix this?

Tags: darksiders

I am playing Darksiders on PC and the following happened:

- lost my save game, I didn't delete the save game it just gone away
- So I started a new game
- Yesterday when I start Darksiders I was surprised that I had the old game back.
- But I lost it (today) again and Darksiders gave me the "new" save game

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you played with Steam running, your saves are in different place than when they are when Steam is not running or logged into another account.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not apply, it seems to be a common issue with Windows XP, which I experienced myself when playing Mass Effect 2, I have read about several other games having an issue with the same fix.

If you changed where the my documents folder points to under the operating system settings, it causes an issue where the game cannot detect the new folder my documents points to, so you should point it back to the default location, C:\Documents and Settings\your name\My Documents\My Games\Darksiders. Don't know if that's the issue you're having, just suggesting it as it might work. Now back to finding a save to help me out of a game-breaking bug I found in the Black Throne!

Answer (score -2):

`C:\Documents and Settings\your name\My Documents\My Games\Darksiders`

Your saved games are stored there. In place of "your name" insert your account name on your computer. After playing Darksiders and saving a game, copy the saved file stored in the above mentioned directory to another place. Then when you want to play paste the file back in the directory. That way you won't lose the saved game.